# Relative paths for included PHP files

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP project with the following directory structure:

```
ROOT
    - PUBLIC
        - CSS
        - JS
    - LIB
        - CONTROLLER
```

All the basic PHP pages are located under PUBLIC folder while all the controllers, models etc are located under the LIB or CONTROLLER folder. In some cases, after the controller has finished processing, it will include a file from the PUBLIC folder to display. What I notice is that the included file cannot find the associated CSS or JS files because it is now working with the relative path of `/LIB/CONTROLLER`.

My question:

1. Is there some way to set a different relative path for the included file without having to modify every single CSS or JS include lines?
2. This problem does not occur if I forward the control using `header (Location...)` but in some instances, I prefer not to do this and just include the page - because I will have to pass heavy objects from the controller to the page using SESSION. Is there some better way to achieve this?

Comment: See HTML5's `<base>`

Comment: great answer - can you please submit as an answer so i can accept

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that's necessary, `<base>` is well documented elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you *include* the CSS and JS files? You should just link them via `link` and `script` elements, respectively. The path is the same, regardless of which part of the server-side script generates it, then.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said I include them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by @Jack T - the solution to this problem is to define the `<base>` element in the included PHP / HTML page. One thing I learnt is that when defining the  element use the full URL including http://

This solved the problem I was facing

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this on all your php files:

if( not defined PATH_TO_ROOT )
  define PATH_TO_ROOT = '.'

So, in your links and stuff, always make the urls with this constant, like this:

url = PATH_TO_ROOT.'/public/css/mycss.css';

** Please note this is just a pseudo-code and not actual PHP code.

Comment: i actually have this but i will have to include this for every single CSS file or JS file - is there a better option? What I am hoping for is that when I include the file, there is a way to define the relative path for that included file. But maybe it is only wishful thinking

Comment: Well, I guess you can make a function that checks the $_SERVER to see the request location. The function receives the css rel path and calculates from there. But I don't think there's no like a magical way.

Answer (score 0):

**/use/absolute/paths/everywhere/on/your/site**

<strike>do/not/use/relative/ones</strike>

^ see, no `/slash`, not good practice.